# Vertically center text in ul a li

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center, vertical-alignment

So, apparently I can't seem to figure out why the text inside the li keeps sticking to the top of it ... I've tried playing with heights, line-heights, vertical-aligns, displays (table, table-cell, inline-block, inline ... ) and all that stuff, but idk why, I can't see what's wrong with it ...

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qdq1jg4g/2/

HTML

```
<header>
    <span id="headerTitle">Title</span>

    <ul id="headerMenu">
        <a href=""><li> Plugin </li></a>
        <a href=""><li> how-to </li></a>
        <a href=""><li> Docs   </li></a>
    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#headerMenu{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    font-size: 16pt;
    right: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#headerMenu a{
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
}

#headerMenu a li{
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a special reason that you put the `a` tags around the `li`? This is not strictly valid HTML.  Can you put the `a` tag within the `li` tag?

Comment: The only reason I do that is so that the entire `li` is a clickable link, instead of just the word itself @MarcAudet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it with the `a` tags embedded with the `li` tags:

```css
header{
    background: #eee;
    color: #333;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 26pt;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}

#headerTitle{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
}  


#headerMenu{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    font-size: 16pt;
    right: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#headerMenu li {
    float: left;
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 20px; /* optional, depends on your layour */
}
#headerMenu a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <span id="headerTitle">Title</span>
    
    <ul id="headerMenu">
        <li><a href="plug-in-link">Plugin</a></li>
        <li><a href="how-to-link">how-to</a></li>
        <li><a href="docs-link">Docs</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's kinda dumb but I didn't thought of increasing `a`'s dimensions, because I was so "focused" on keeping it in that place, in order to make it work the way I wanted ... 
Anyways, worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: This simple looking layout is a bit harder to achieve than it looks, it took me a few tries to sort it out.  By the way, this problem is closely related to building a 3-column page layout in which the three columns take on the height of the tallest column.  All the best!